# for loop is causing code to crash: PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import PIL   
import os.path  
from PIL import Image

def get_images(directory=None):
    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() 

    image_list = [] 
    file_list = []

    directory_list = os.listdir(directory) 
    for entry in directory_list:
        absolute_filename = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        try:
            image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename)
            file_list += [entry]
            image_list += [image]
        except IOError:
            pass 
    return image_list, file_list

def frame_image(image):

    family = Image.open(image)
    width, height = family.size
    familysize = width, height
    frame = Image.open('border.png')
    resizedborder = frame.resize(familysize)
    family.paste(resizedborder, mask=resizedborder)
    return family

def frame_all_images():
    directory = os.getcwd()

    new_directory = os.path.join(directory, "Framed Images")
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    except:
        pass
    images, files = get_images(directory)
    for n in range(len(images)):
        new_image = frame_image(images[n])
        new_name = os.path.join(new_directory, files + ".png")
        new_image.save(new_name)
    print 'Success! All images have been framed!'
```

[image: Picture of error given.]

Crashes. I really can't figure it out. Works when I specify one picture, but, crashes when I give it a list of images when I use the "frame_all_images" function. I imagine it's the way it's getting the images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `new_image = frame_image(images[n])`, Here `images[n]` is an Image object, and not a path to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You're iterating over Image object and not Image files or paths.

```
def frame_all_images():
    directory = os.getcwd()

    new_directory = os.path.join(directory, "Framed Images")
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    except:
        pass
    images, files = get_images(directory)
    for n in range(len(files)):
        new_image = frame_image(files[n])
        new_name = os.path.join(new_directory, files + ".png")
        new_image.save(new_name)
    print 'Success! All images have been framed!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You get images and files using get_images. Please iterate over files to get file and images to get image object.

```
import PIL
import os.path
from PIL import Image


def get_images(directory=None):
    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd()

    image_list = []
    file_list = []

    directory_list = os.listdir(directory)
    for entry in directory_list:
        absolute_filename = os.path.join(directory, entry)
        try:
            #print absolute_filename
            if ".png"  in absolute_filename:
                image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename)
                file_list += [entry]
                image_list += [image]
        except IOError:
            pass
    return image_list, file_list


def frame_image(image):
    family = Image.open(image)
    width, height = family.size
    familysize = width, height
    frame = Image.open('border.png')
    resizedborder = frame.resize(familysize)
    family.paste(resizedborder, mask=resizedborder)
    return family


def frame_all_images():
    directory = os.getcwd()

    new_directory = os.path.join(directory, "Framed Images")
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    except:
        pass
    images, files = get_images(directory)
    for n in range(len(files)):
        new_image = frame_image(files[n])
        new_name = os.path.join(new_directory, files + ".png")
        new_image.save(new_name)
    print 'Success! All images have been framed!'

def main():
    frame_all_images()

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The frame_image function uses a string path and not 'PngImageFile' object.
get_images function opens the path and you append the 'PngImageFile' to the image variable, so in frame_all_images function you are trying to open an already opened file.

The following change will fix the issue:

```
def frame_all_images():
    directory = os.getcwd()

    new_directory = os.path.join(directory, "Framed Images")
    try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
    except:
        pass

    images, files = get_images(directory)
    for n in range(len(images)):
        new_image = frame_image(files[n])
        new_name = os.path.join(new_directory, files[n] + ".png")
        new_image.save(new_name)
    print('Success! All images have been framed!')
```